# Parse gt06 GPS string

Tags: node.js, gps

i've the following string from the Gt06 v3 gps:
12060e163121c8020f9bf20aa06bad371d52014e03235a008a7d00269dfe0d

But i don't know how to parse to string and extract the latitude and logitude, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1) The value is being calculated using the following formula:

d - degree
m - minutes
s - seconds
ms - milliseconds

If a longitude is west or a latitude is south, then the value is being multiplied by –1.

Answer (score 0):

```
longitude = (180 * n_lng) / 324000000.0;
latitude = (90 * n_lat) / 162000000.0;
```

`n_lng` and `n_lat` are the number converted from the hex.